# How to create crystal report with c# 2015 wpf with sqlite database?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sqlite

I have created windows form application in `vs2015` c# with `sqlite3` .Please any one teach me how to create a report in crystal report. In C# / WPF.. I have tried with most of examples in web but those are not working with vs2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio version shouldn't play a role.

I'll give you a link with description how to add Crystal Reports to WinForms project:
[Basic Crystal Report Tutorial with example in Windows Forms (WinForms) Application using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Basic-Crystal-Report-Tutorial-with-example-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

One difference is your project has SQLite database, so you should fill your class (in example it's calld Customers) with some other way

How to use SQLite in WPF application you can learn from this link:
[Using SQLite in your C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application)